# is it correct or no? ROLLEDBACK AND COMMIT

Tags: transactions, commit, rollback

it's about COMMIT statement and ROLLBACK statement in SQL

I know that the ROLLBACK statement is the inverse of COMMIT statement.

what if we said "The COMMIT statement is the inverse of ROLLBACK statement"

Is it correct or no? if it's no explain it please

thank you for help

Comment: No it is not the same.  if you rollback, there is nothing to commit afterwards until you perform some more DML

Comment: Neither is the "inverse" of the other. Once you did a commit, you can not rollback. And once you did a rollback, you can't commit. You can only say one is the opposite of the other

Answer (score 0):

From SQL Server's perspective the usage of 'inverse' may be misleading with "nested" transaction

> [COMMIT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/commit-transaction-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15):
> Marks the end of a successful implicit or explicit transaction.
>
> [ROLLBACK](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/rollback-transaction-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15):
> Rolls back an explicit or implicit transaction to the beginning of the transaction, or to a savepoint inside the transaction.

Example:

```
BEGIN TRAN
BEGIN TRAN
SELECT 'sth';
COMMIT;
SELECT @@TRANCOUNT;
-- 1
```

vs

```
BEGIN TRAN
BEGIN TRAN
SELECT 'sth';
ROLLBACK;
SELECT @@TRANCOUNT;
-- 0 (nothing to commit)
```

**[db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=21bc5788c7d542e5d8e6802c53e78fdb)**